# reading in Firebase Database with Query return null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here i am try to get the liked-event node key by matching the userId and eventId where i got from event node. I did some code but the query return null on the likedEventKey.

This is my event node
I trying to include loopin and without loopin in the onDataChange method. The result is same. It give me null.

The node here is

[the node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl4YK.png)

```
    private String likedEventKey;

 /*
     * Attach the data to the UI
     * */
    private void showEventData(Event event) {
        textView.setText(event.getEventKey() + ", " + currentUser.getUid() + "," + likedEventKey);
    }

/*
     * Method for checking like event status in Db based on EventKey
     * */
    private void checkLikeEventStatusInDb() {
        Query query = mLikedEventDbReference
                .child("liked-event")
                .orderByChild("eventId")
                .equalTo(event.getEventKey());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    likedEvent = ds.getValue(LikedEvent.class);
                    if (likedEvent != null) {
                        String eventId = likedEvent.getEventId();
                        String eventKey = event.getEventKey();
                        if (eventId.equalsIgnoreCase(eventKey)) {
                            checkUsernameInLikeEventStatusInDb();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Timber.e("Error while fetch letch liked event %s",
                        databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Method for checking like event status in Db based on UserId
     * */
    private void checkUsernameInLikeEventStatusInDb() {
        Query query = mLikedEventDbReference
                .child("liked-event")
                .orderByChild("userId")
                .equalTo(currentUser.getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    likedEvent = ds.getValue(LikedEvent.class);
                    if (likedEvent != null) {
                        likedEvent.setLikedEventKey(ds.getKey());
                        String userIdInLikedEvent = likedEvent.getUserId();
                        if (userIdInLikedEvent.equalsIgnoreCase(currentUser.getUid())) {
                            likedEventKey = likedEvent.getLikedEventKey();
                            Timber.d("likedEventKey: %s", likedEventKey);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Timber.e("Error while fetch letch liked event %s",
                        databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

my expected return is i got the liked-event child key based on the userId and eventId.

Comment: what is the value of `event.getEventKey()`?

Comment: the latest node of liked-event node. so lkh8...na

Answer (score 0):

The below query will only return one **liked-event** node(check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query.html#is-equal)) . Therefore the for loop inside `onDataChange()` doesn't make any sense. It is looping through the children inside a **liked-event**

```
Query query = mLikedEventDbReference
     .child("liked-event")
     .orderByChild("userId")
     .equalTo(currentUser.getUid());
```

By changing the code as mentioned below, i guess you'll be able to achieve  what you need.

```
    Query query = mLikedEventDbReference
            .child("liked-event")
            .orderByChild("eventId");

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                likedEvent = ds.getValue(LikedEvent.class);
                if (likedEvent != null) {
                    String eventId = likedEvent.getEventId();
                    String eventKey = ds.getKey();
                    if (eventId.equalsIgnoreCase(eventKey)) {
                        checkUsernameInLikeEventStatusInDb();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

You can change the other method also similarly to this.

Comment: i assign mLikedEventDbRefence variable like 
mLikedEventDbRefence = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("liked-event")

is there any differences with
mLikedEventDbRefence = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference() ?

Comment: Yes. So you have already referred to the child node 'liked-event' via get reference. Therefore, you don't need to do that again in the query. In that way you are trying to refer to a 'liked-event' node in a 'liked-event' node. Just removing the reference to the 'liked-event' node in getReference() will be more elegant.

Comment: i figured out my problem. It's better to check in one method it's makes clear. thanks for commenting bro